# How build.gradle's plugins block works inside gradle code base?

Tags: gradle, build.gradle, gradle-plugin

Now I'm trying to understand how build.gradle works.
And I found that unqualified names in `build.gradle` file are properties or methods of Project object (mostly).

I found like below in Project interface (and also impl class of Project).

```
void dependencies(Closure configureClosure);

void repositories(Closure configureClosure);
```

But I can't find any `plugins` method declaration.

I guess there are parsing logics to read `plugins` block in gradle.
Please give me a hint to follow logic in gradle code base. Thank you.